# I render an object with its texture and sometimes the canvas becomes white afterwards

Tags: firefox, three.js, screen, rendering

I have this problem only with Firefox 24.0 :

I render my scene with an object and its texture plus 2 point lights and most of the time after the first rendering, the canvas becomes white.

The thing is that I display several canvases (12) and they become all white at the same time.

I don't have this problem with Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m nor IE 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround thanks to a colleague.

Actually with Firefox, during a repaint or a reflow, the canvas can turn white because of the way firefox handles the video card.

So, instead of appending the Three's dom element directly into the DOM, I've created a new canvas which is put into the dom and then I draw the Three's dom element onto it.

```
var onscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = onscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(threeJsDomElement, 0, 0);
```

It's a bit slower than the general method but it works well.